# how to stop an in-process upload in plupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plupload

`up.removeFile(file)` works only if the upload is not in progress.

Is this a bug, or exists some other function I missed to call?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This way I could make it work.

Every added files has it own cancel function:

```
var status_before = file.status;
up.removeFile(file);                
if(up.state == plupload.STARTED && status_before == plupload.UPLOADING)
{
  up.stop();
  up.start();
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the 2 for its corresponding constant. Thanks for this answer. I have to wait 24h to award the bounty...

Comment: we can also write: up.removeFile(file.id).

Answer (score 1):

Hide the container will stop uploads. Ex :

```
var max = 10;
var count = 0;

uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, info){
    count++;
    if (count >= max){
            $('#container').hide();
            console.log('limit reached');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not possible (yet): https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/168

If you only use a specific transport (HTML5/XHR) you could do it by calling `.abort()` on the XHR object though.